# angular - how to display array as multiple lines in a table cell

Tags: angular

Sorry I am new to angular and trying to learning some basics while making some app myself.

I have the following that that outputs an array in the table cell 
TEST1,TEST2,TEST3

My goal is to make it to display as

TEST1

TEST2

TEST3

getStatus(element.message) returns an array that is constructed by

array.push(match[0]) in a for loop

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketStatus">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center w-6">
        Status
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ getStatus(element.message) }}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you are using Angular material. What you could do is populating your cells using a foreach on displayedColumns?

```
<table cdk-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" cdkColumnDef="{{ col }}">
     <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ col }}</th>
     <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row; let i = index"> {{ getFieldValue(i, col) }}   </td>
   </ng-container> 

   <tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Please note: the example is a CDK-table, but it is almost similar to Angular Material Table since it is derived from CdkTable.

I created a Stackblitz. Maybe you can get some inspiration:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bes8zf

Comment: thank you for your inspiration. I think I didn't make my question clear. From you example, my question is the if the value in column "Name" can be an array, how can I display it properly as multiple line in the same cell?

Comment: thank you for your insights again. I made it working using    
 <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketStatus">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center w-6">
        Status
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><ng-container *ngFor="let status of getStatus(element.message)">{{ status }}<br></ng-container></td>
    </ng-container>